# Node error when running TypeORM migrations

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typeorm

I'm getting an error when running

```
yarn run migration:run
```

In `package.json` the script for that is

```
"migration:run": "dotenv -e ../.env DB_PORT=4420 npx run typeorm migration:run",
```

Here's the error:

```
❯ yarn run migration:run    
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ dotenv -e ../.env DB_PORT=4420 npx run typeorm migration:run
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn DB_PORT=4420 ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn DB_PORT=4420',
  path: 'DB_PORT=4420',
  spawnargs: [ 'npx', 'run', 'typeorm', 'migration:run' ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have another Docker container using port 5432 for Postgres, which is why I have it set to 4420 and am passing that in as part of the command. I've found a handful of similar errors from searches, but none as a result of running this command. I've tried everything I can think of, including deleting `yarn.lock` and `/node_modules` and re-running `yarn`, and that still didn't fix it. Does anyone have some advice on how I can get past this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this, the issue was with the way I defined the command in `package.json`. I changed this line:

```
"migration:run": "dotenv -e ../.env DB_PORT=4420 npx run typeorm migration:run"
```

to

```
"migration:run": "DB_PORT=4420 dotenv -e ../.env npm run typeorm migration:run"
```

and now it works fine. If you're using `dotenv`, you have to define any env vars you want the cli command to use first, *then* call `dotenv`. Also, I had to change `npx` to `npm`, and now it works fine.